# How to read and parse this JSON using Jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson

```
[
      {
      "id": 8,
      "name": "D.F. y Área Metropolitana",
      "areas":       [
                  {
            "id": 15,
            "name": "Centro",
            "state_id": 8
         },
                  {
            "id": 1008,
            "name": "Todo D.F. y Área Metropolitana",
            "state_id": 8
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Comment: did you try anything?

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jackson provides many ways of reading this JSON. One simple way would be doing something like this:

```
Map<String, Object> result = new ObjectMapper().readValue("JSON_Input_Here", Map.class);
```

Additionally, you could do something like:

```
JsonNode input = new ObjectMapper().readTree("JSON_Input_Here");
```

I'm not sure how a map would handle a Json array, but the JsonNode object lets you check the type of the Json input (Object vs Array ...).

Here is a simple and quick resource you can use:
http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes